# Default checking a checkbox

Tags: html

Is there a difference between these two ways of default checking a checkbox:

```
document.getElementById(checkboxId).defaultChecked = checked;
```

vs

```
document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked = checked;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i guess theres no difference if you use it as a setter. but if you use it as getter there will be difference.

becouse .defaultChecked as the name already telling you is checking the default value not the current one.

Answer (score 10):

`defaultChecked` is the *default* state, `checked` is the *current* state.

If you change `defaultChecked` and then press a `<input type="reset">` then the checkbox should reset to the state specified in the `defaultChecked` property.

If you change `checked`, then the state will change immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The defaultChecked property returns the default value of the checked attribute.
This property returns true if the checkbox is checked by default, otherwise it returns false.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp

The checked property sets or returns the checked state of a checkbox.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. It is dreadful. Even here it doesn't make mention that `defaultChecked` can be *set* (which is what the question is doing).